# Insert Auto increment C# ... Error Cant be Null

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I get the error that ID cant be Null, but it should auto increment

Using this code:

```
 cn.Open();
 cmd.CommandText = " insert into Firmen(Firmenname,UstID,Telefonnummer) Values('" + tbFName.Text + "','" + tbUstID.Text + "','" + tbTelF.Text + "')";
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 cn.Close();
```

I thought it would auto increment when I just Ignore the ID. Please help me

Comment: What server software (s.g. SQL Server) are you using?  Is the column set to increment automatically in the table definition?

Comment: Also note that you should be using parameters instead of string concatenation, especially when using user input.

Comment: Is your primary key column set to Identity?

Comment: 1. ID field must have identity specification 
2. use SqlCommand with parameters to avoid sql injection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Was ID set as identity in your create table script?